# Building a GTK Gridview like a gallery with different heights

Tags: gtk3, pygtk

I'm trying to build a GTK Grid with random cell height, here is the result for now:

https://framapiaf.s3.framasoft.org/framapiaf/media_attachments/files/003/551/599/original/d513c5fb60a87e1e.png

But I'm still having some issues so I was wondering if any already writen layout exists to achieve something like that. My code is ugly so, don't juge, it was just something to try it:

```py
        column_rows = [0,0,0,0]
        row = 0
        column = 0
        from random import randint
        width = int(self.get_size().width/4)
        while( row != 100):
            text = ""
            for i in range(0,randint(0, 100)):
                text = text+"bla "
            notear = {"shorttext":text, "title":"title"}
            note = NoteWidget(notear)
            note.set_size_request(width, -1)
            note.show_all()
            note.modify_bg(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.color_parse('white'))
            height = note.size_request().height
            self.note_container.attach(note, column, column_rows[column], 1, height)
            column_rows[column] = column_rows[column]+height
            print(height)
            if(column == 3):
                column = 0
                row = row+1

            else:

                column = column + 1


        self.note_container.show_all()
```

What my current code does is setting a fix width to child, then getting the height and adding it to the column grid so that next children will be below

So is there any layout, lib, or what so ever already doing that in gtk ?

Thanks !!

Comment: Is a [GtkFlowBox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.24/GtkFlowBox.html) what you're looking for?